# .jar throwing UnsatisfiedLinkError only outside of IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using `Netbeans` to create a java application.  The program works fine when I hit run in Netbeans.  The problem is when I build the app and run it from the `dist` folder it throws the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.  I know this is caused by the libraries.

The error message is:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you start your app from the commandline? Did you specify the required jar files?

Comment: "java - cp lib/jssc.jar -jar perpetuallinegraph.jar"

Comment: I think the SerialNativeInterface has some native library to load, and it is not finding them. Perhaps also a 32 vs 64 bit problem?

Comment: I think it can't find the native library, but I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

Comment: What OS are you running on? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I am using windows 7 64 bit, JDK 1.7, and the processing library

Comment: When you start it in the commandline, are you sure it also uses the 64 bit sdk? (Or better: The same as Netbeans uses)

Comment: The computer is using the same java platform to execute the file.